# How to determine the available chunk size in server socket?

Tags: java

I need to transfer a file between two clients. The sender will send the file chunk by chunk to the server. Now, how to determine the chunk/buffer size available in 
the server socket ?

Comment: Create your own little cute protocol.... Send size in your format before sending actual data....

Comment: Why do you need to know this? With TCP/IP the size of the packets arriving at the server can be different from the ones sent.